# python - why does multiplication of long and float produce decimal-like answer?

Tags: python, precision, python-2.x

In this example:

```
long_ten = 10**21
print('  type(long_ten):', type(long_ten))
print('     long_ten: {:52,f}'.format(long_ten))
tenth = 0.1
print('  type(tenth):', type(tenth))
print('   float(52f): {:52.52f}'.format(tenth))
float_res = tenth * long_ten
print('\n  type(float_res):', type(float_res))
print(' float(52f): {:15.52f}'.format(float_res))
```

Why does multiplying a long and float result in a float with decimal-like precision?

```
type(long_ten): <type 'long'>
long_ten:                 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.000000
type(tenth): <type 'float'>
float(52f): 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541016

type(float_res): <type 'float'>
float(52f): 100000000000000000000.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I would expect the result to be:

```
100000000000000005551.1151231257827021181583404541016...
```

I understand why the result type is float  - b/c it is wider than long

NOTE - this is using python 2 (if that matters)

Comment: tenth gets lost in the relative precision

Answer (score 2):

100000000000000000000 is representable as float:

```
>>> n = 100000000000000000000
>>> int(float(n))
100000000000000000000L
```

The next larger float is 100000000000000016384:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> next(int(float(i)) for i in count(n) if int(float(i)) != n)
100000000000000016384L
```

Thus the float closest to your expected 100000000000000005551.115... is  100000000000000000000, so that's what you get.

Why are floats this large always integers? Well, you can see in binary it's already 67 bits:

```
>>> bin(n)
'0b1010110101111000111010111100010110101100011000100000000000000000000'
>>> len(bin(n)[2:])
67
```

But [floats only store the most significant 53 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64). So since the front bit is worth 2<sup>66</sup>, the tail bit is already worth 2<sup>66-52</sup> = 16384. As we've already seen above. So all 53 bits are worth integers and thus the whole number is an integer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point numbers are just a certain set of fractions whose denominators are powers of 2.  2^-*n* has *n* digits after the decimal, so a `float` can easily have 53 non-zero digits (more for large numbers, since no power of 2 is a power of 10).  You're just printing (nearly) that "full" number; we usually don't do that, since all but the first 16 (or so) are just "noise" determined by those first few.